# Issue getting CORS to work with JQuery client, Node / Express server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, cors

I am having an issue getting cross origin resource sharing working with cookies.  Here is my setup:

**Client:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/processReq',
        data: params,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials:true},
        crossDomain: true,
        success: ...
    });
```

I have debugged the client in the browser, and have verified that XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials is in fact true.

**Server:**

I am setting the following headers:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

My issue is that I cannot get the session cookie to be stored by the browser, and sent on a subsequent request to the server.

Here are the response headers in the browser:

```
{
    "server": "nginx/1.2.6",
    "date": "Fri, 01 Feb 2013 23:46:07 GMT",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "306",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "set-cookie": [
        "id=s%3Azm1m...NXe4Lkr9rLw; Domain=api.mydomain.io; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 01 Feb 2014 23:46:07 GMT; HttpOnly"
    ]
}
```

Every time I test, I do not get a cookie sent to the server.  Am I missing something?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` with `('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)`.  You need to explicitly set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to one value.  If you still want the '*' behavior, set the value to the requests `origin` header programatically.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control :

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server
>   must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason that I added * rather than the actual origin is that there is no "origin" header being passed in from my browser (latest Chrome).  Perhaps this is my problem.  When does the 'origin' header get passed?  Is there a parameter that I need to set on the client in order to instruct the browser to pass the origin header?

Comment: It might not be sent if the request isn't a cross-origin request.  You could always set a header to the appropriate domain name yourself.  I'd get it working by switching out the '*' for the domain you are using, and go from there.

Comment: UGH - it looks like the application that I was using (iodocs) built a proxy server to take the requests, and then post from the server.  This is the reason there was no origin, and cookie problems.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: No problem.  That's the "easy" solution to the CORS problems. ;p

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant option that side-steps CORS altogether is using a hidden iframe and `window.postMessage`.

The `postMessage` API let's two browser frames communicate cross-domain. The basic design is as follows:

1. load main page on `domain-1.com`
2. main page loads hidden iframe from `domain-2.com`
3. hidden iframe loads javascript to interface with `domain-2.com` APIs

Any time the main page wishes to talk cross-domain, it proxies the request through the hidden iframe. There is no CORS to deal with — none!

A Few Tutorials:

- http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage